# (Python) The validation and input works properly for binary but not in other base number systems

Tags: python, validation

I'm a first year college IT student and we were tasked by our professor to make a number system converter. We were not allowed to use any method that would automatically convert to a number system.

I used this code to validate for the binary input:

```
 def base2():
    s = {'0','1'}
    y = input('Allowed numbers are "0-1", Enter your whole number: ')
    val = set(y)
    
    while not (s == val or val == {'0'} or val == {'1'}):
        y = input('Allowed numbers are "0-1", Enter your whole number: ')
        val = set(y)
    return y
```

For the other number system above base-2, I just added the missing validation.

For example in base-3:

```
def base3():
    s = {'0','1','2'}
    y = input('Allowed numbers are "0-2", Enter your whole number: ')
    val = set(y)
    
    while not (s == val or val == {'0'} or val == {'1'} or val == {'2'}):
        y = input('Allowed numbers are "0-2", Enter your whole number: ')
        val = set(y)
    return y
```

I just added to the ending of each validation. But for some reason, it requires that all numbers or a repetition of one of the allowed numbers for it to be validated.

Input/Output:

```
Allowed numbers are "0-2", Enter your whole number: 20
Allowed numbers are "0-2", Enter your whole number: 111
['1', '1', '1']
The decimal value of    " 111 "   base- 3  is 13

Allowed numbers are "0-2", Enter your whole number: 211
Allowed numbers are "0-2", Enter your whole number: 210
['2', '1', '0']
The decimal value of    " 210 "   base- 3  is 21
```

Would appreciate any kind of help <3

Comment: Also, try to refactor your code so that you don't have the same logic (and thus the same bugs, if any) in multiple places. A central worker function which works for any base, and which you call with different parameters for each base, would work well here. See also [DRY Principle.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)

Comment: Will try to practice it. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use following condition:

```
while any(x not in s for x in val):
```

instead of:

```
while not (s == val or val == {'0'} or val == {'1'} or val == {'2'})
```

When you convert to set, we can't guarantee it's order as set itself is not ordered. Hence, checking `s == val` may not always work as you think. Also, user can enter any combination of numbers.